# Lumen: PHPUnit give failure but testing passed in Gitlab CI Runner

Tags: docker, phpunit, laravel-5.1, lumen, gitlab-ci-runner

This is my first time to use testing in my project. I use Gitlab CI and gitlab runner to perform test. But something weird happened, when phpunit executed the output is failure, but the test result in gitlab is **passed**. Gitlab should be show **failed** result.

I use Lumen 5.1. And Gitlab Runner using docker.

This is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file

```yaml
image: dragoncapital/comic:1.0.0

stages:
 - test

cache:
 paths:
  - vendor/

before_script:
 - bash .gitlab-ci.sh > /dev/null

test:7.0:
 script:
  - phpunit
```

This is my `.gitlab-sh.sh` file

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# We need to install dependencies only for Docker
[[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && exit 0

set -xe

composer install
cp .env.testing .env
```

The log and result:

[image: Fail test, passed status]

As you can see the phpunit test fail, but the status in gitlab CI is passed.

**Update:**

The log ouput is quite different in my local computer, but the results are error/fail.

[image: Local phpunit]

Answer (score 0):

At least I figured out what wrong with this test. There are two `phpunit` in this system, and I called the wrong one.

First, I installed `phpunit` using `apt-get` command, so phpunit is installed as Ubuntu package.

And secondly, Laravel/Lumen provided `phpunit` in `vendor/bin`.

When I just typing `phpunit` in terminal, it call phpunit that provided by Ubuntu, and this give me unexpected results. But, everything ok when I call `vendor/bin/phpunit` instead of just `phpunit`.